# Android OpenGL ES image filters

Tags: android, image-processing, opengl-es

I found this [example](https://github.com/chrisbatt/AndroidFastImageProcessing/tree/master/examples/AllFiltersExample) and I am making some filters on realtime camera. When I use **GlassSphereFilter** or **SphereRefractionFilter** I get sphere on black background, and I want to achieve something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcLzo.png). Can anyone help me?

Here is part of the code:

```
view = new FastImageProcessingView(this);
pipeline = new FastImageProcessingPipeline();
view.setPipeline(pipeline);
setContentView(view);
input = new CameraPreviewInput(view);
filter = new SphereRefractionFilter(new PointF(0.43f, 0.5f), 0.25f, 0.71f, 0.5f);
screen = new ScreenEndpoint(pipeline);
input.addTarget(screen);
filter.addTarget(screen);
pipeline.addRootRenderer(input);
pipeline.startRendering();
```

Is there a way ti show two surfaceViews with camera in same time? One to show normal image and other to show sphere?

Comment: So all you want to add is the original image in the background of your sphere?

Comment: Not static image, it is camera view. But yes, original view without filter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this library :
https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage

Comment: Again I get only sphere without background.

Comment: You must blend sphere image with background image use Blend Filter. Like this: https://ilyashubin.github.io/FilterBlend/

Comment: Check GPUImageSourceOverBlendFilter